# iOS - "Received memory warning" when viewing specific PDF in UIWebView

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, memory, uiwebview

I have an iPad app which has a UIViewController containing a UIWebView for viewing documents.  I've been using this happily for some time with no problems.  However I've come across a 13 page PDF document which the UIWebView loads OK but when you scroll through the pages it causes the app to crash, unless there are very few other apps loaded at the time.  When running the app in debug mode, I get the message "Received memory warning" in the debug window.  When the app crashes I often (but not always) get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I have successfully viewed much bigger PDFs than this one in the past, but this one does have more graphics.  I have an iPhone app which uses the same UIViewController and this loads and views the PDF fine with no errors.  Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Been there, got the Tshirt. Viewing bigger PDFs within a webView will rather quickly get your memory exhausted. Your options are slim; A. use a native implementation to display the PDF, B. split the PDF into smaller chunks (pages) and show them seperately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If I email the PDF to myself I can view it fine in the native mail app (and I like the thumbnail viewer that comes with it).  Is this app using a different control to view the PDF?  Is this control an option for developers to use?